# Completed exchange in the scope of http4-component

Tags: apache-camel

I have a simple Camel route consuming messages from ActiveMQ, processing and forwarding them to Rest webservices:

```
from("activemq:MyQueue").process("MyProcessor").to("http4:uri");
```

I configure concurrentConsumers=100 in the connectionfactory from activemq-component.

In the documentation:

```
if asyncConsumer is disabled(default) then the Exchange is fully processed before the JmsConsumer will pickup the next message from the JMS queue
```

Question:
In my route, when is the exchange of each message is fully processed?  After the http-callee receives http response?  If that is the case, I assume, my route configuration means:

1. At beginning, 1 message is consumed from each consumers and forwarded to the http
2. Each of these 100 consumers is waiting and will only consume again if the current http call gets http response from the current message.

Another question:
I found out that the default value of http4 component option connectionsPerRoute=20.  As I have 100 consumers, should I set connectionsPerRoute=100?

Thank you,
Hadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each jms thread runs simultaneously without knowing each other. in your example 100 threads are processed at the same time without getting blocked.You do not need to play in the number of threads of the http component, as this is done through jms threads from start to finish.

Comment: I can rely on this statement "if asyncConsumer is disabled(default) then the Exchange is fully processed before the JmsConsumer will pickup the next message from the JMS queue"?  Do each of the consumers really consume the next message from the Queue after the current messageExchange is completed?  This is the feature I want.  I did need to configure connectionsPerRoute as the default value is 20.  I have 100 consumers, each of them is supposed to route the message concurrently to a single http-uri.  So I need connectionsPerRoute=100.  If I stay with 20, I could see WAITING in log.